# Add-appxPackage deployment failed: does not find files

Tags: powershell, windows-10-universal

I am trying to deploy windows 10 app that I created to a laptop. In my computer everything goes fine, but in the laptop the Add-appPackage first recognizes the relevant package files, but when running the line in the script that makes the unbundle it fails and returns with: 
' The system cannot find the file specified' eventhough the files exists.
I tried to make a deploy using the -register flag from working solution directory but the result was the same.
I use in my computer Windows 10 HOME and the Laptop is Windows 10 Pro but I think it does not matter.

The line in the script file generated by the visual studio packager which fails is:

```
Add-AppxPackage -Path $DeveloperPackagePath.FullName -DependencyPath $DependencyPackages.FullName -ForceApplicationShutdown
```

I checked the variables - they contain correct data.
Afterwards it outputs the error with the line:

```
    $Error[0] # Dump details about the last error
```

that does not give me too much details about which file is missing as you can see in the full output:

```
C:\users\User\AlephBet_1.0.4.0_Test\Dependencies\x86\Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.3.appx
C:\users\User\AlephBet_1.0.4.0_Test\Dependencies\x86\Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.3.appx
C:\users\User\AlephBet_1.0.4.0_Test\Dependencies\x86\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.14.00.appx
C:\users\User\AlephBet_1.0.4.0_Test\Dependencies\x64\Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.3.appx
C:\users\User\AlephBet_1.0.4.0_Test\Dependencies\x64\Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.3.appx
C:\users\User\AlephBet_1.0.4.0_Test\Dependencies\x64\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx
Add-AppxPackage : The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.


At C:\users\User\AlephBet_1.0.4.0_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1:388 char:13
+             Add-AppxPackage -Path $DeveloperPackagePath.FullName -Dep ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-AppxPackage],     FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.A    ddAppx 
   PackageCommand
```

I tried also getting information with get-AppxLog but it does log the error.

1. What happens? What is missing? Is there a way to get more information about the error?
2. Where does Windows 10 put the appx? Is there a way to make a bypass and take the files from an existing executable version, something like .exe files and copy them as is to the laptop?

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange. Here are a couple things you can try to narrow down the issue. First, try to update the script by adding the line “Write-Host $DeveloperPackagePath.FullName” right before the failing line. Make sure that file exists. Next, make sure that all 6 of the listed dependency packages exist. Finally, you can try to open a new powershell prompt and execute “Add-AppxPackage <appx path>” for each of the 6 listed dependency packages one at a time, then execute it for your appx/appxbundle directly.  That should give a better idea of what’s failing.

Comment: I checked all variables participated in that line. Everything fine. Ofcourse all files exists.

Comment: I checked all variables participated in that line. Everything fine, ofcourse all files exists. I could not wait for a proper solution, so I had no choice but to change the operating system to Windows 10 HOME and it worked fluently. For some reason it seems that the Windows 10 Pro cannot run code created with Visual Studio created with the HOME ver. To be sure I used very minimal code of my app: only one page with a menu without items and without background image and it did not work either.

Comment: That's very odd - I've never heard of that behavior before. I'm glad you got it working. Are you able to use Home or did you need any features only available in Pro?

Comment: Nothiing. The app I checked finally was very minor. only a page with a frame filled with other page containing a menu. That's all. Maybe the laptop seller did not make a full installation of the Pro? odd.